# Where to call restartLoader in ListView Fragment using ActionBarSherlock and SQLiteCursorLoader

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I'm doing a ListView in a fragment using loaders, ActionBarSherlock and SqliteCursorLoader.  The ListView basically shows a list of dates and GPS coordinates. I can load the inital ListView just fine.  I want to be able to reload the ListView upon clicking of a button to go forward and back in time and show the relevant data.

My problem is that I must not be calling restartLoader() in the right place, Eclipse is giving me a compile error when I try and call it using "this" as the third parameter.  It is saying that "this" is of type View, and it needs to be of type LoaderCallbacks.  How do I get the third parameter?   I tried to use all variations of getSherlockActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID) and tried to cast to LoaderCallbacks and no luck.

This is my first attempt using a Loader.

Here is my onActivityCreated:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
    mGPSDC = new GPSDateCoordinates();
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated");
    CalcDate();
    //enables buttons for next and previous months
    GetPreviousFollowingMonths();
    adapter= new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, null, new String[] {
            myDbHelper.COLUMN_DISTANCE, myDbHelper.COLUMN_FORMATTEDSTART }, 
            new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.value },0);
    lvReports.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnDate.setText(getMonth(BaseMonth) + " " + String.valueOf(BaseYear));
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);


    // show next month's data
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                getSherlockActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
                getSherlockActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID).forceLoad();


        }
    });

}
```

and here is the Loader code:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {

    loader = new SQLiteCursorLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), myDbHelper,
            myDbHelper.getSQLArrayOfDatesDistances(BaseYear,BaseMonth),null);
    return loader;

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor) {
    adapter.changeCursor(cursor);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    adapter.changeCursor(null);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `YourActivityClassName.this` rather than `this` (which is the View.OnClickListener class instance) in order to refer to the Activity's instance.

Comment: That doesn't work, it's still showing a compile error though I'm calling getSherlockActivity().

Comment: @KristyWelsh - what is your class that does implement LoaderCallbacks? If it is your fragment, you'll need to use `FragmentClassName.this` - the point is that `this` inside of the listener is the listener, not the Fragment/Activity that actually is controlling the loading.